# Python Dataframe - Remove duplicate TRUE on a date except the first occurrence

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a couple of columns in a data frame. I'm trying to create a third column where all duplicate TRUES are changed to false, except the first TRUE of the day.

[image]

I tried playing around with .duplicated but couldn't get it to work. I then gave up and moved to an inefficient, slow, loop.

```
    for i in range(0, len(DF)): #From row 0 to last row in data frame, iterate through i
    j = DF.columns.get_loc('Desired Column') #column

    if DF.iat[i, j] == 'TRUE' and DF.iat[i - 1, j] == 'TRUE':  
        DF.at[i, 'Desired Column'] = FALSE
```

This is also didn't work at all - didn't seem to change anything.

```
Date,True_False
1/01/2019,FALSE
1/01/2019,FALSE
1/01/2019,TRUE
1/01/2019,TRUE
1/01/2019,FALSE
1/01/2019,FALSE
1/01/2019,FALSE
1/01/2019,FALSE
2/01/2019,FALSE
2/01/2019,FALSE
2/01/2019,TRUE
2/01/2019,FALSE
2/01/2019,FALSE
2/01/2019,FALSE
2/01/2019,FALSE
2/01/2019,FALSE
3/01/2019,FALSE
3/01/2019,FALSE
3/01/2019,TRUE
3/01/2019,TRUE
3/01/2019,TRUE
3/01/2019,TRUE
3/01/2019,FALSE
3/01/2019,FALSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `cumsum` within Date and make everything > 1 False.

```
df['Desired'] = np.where(df.groupby('Date')['True_False'].cumsum() <= 1, df['True_False'], False)
```

Comment: Awesome - this seems to work and I understand how it works!

Answer (score 2):

You can do `groupby` and use `idxmax` to get the index of the first `True` value in each group.

Then use that in `np.where` to replace values.

```
a = df.groupby('Date')['True_False'].transform('idxmax')
df['first_True'] = np.where(df.index != a, False,True)
```

**Output**

```
      Date  True_False  first_True
0   1/01/2019   False   False
1   1/01/2019   False   False
2   1/01/2019   True    True
3   1/01/2019   True    False
4   1/01/2019   False   False
5   1/01/2019   False   False
6   1/01/2019   False   False
7   1/01/2019   False   False
8   2/01/2019   False   False
9   2/01/2019   False   False
10  2/01/2019   True    True
11  2/01/2019   False   False
12  2/01/2019   False   False
13  2/01/2019   False   False
14  2/01/2019   False   False
15  2/01/2019   False   False
16  3/01/2019   False   False
17  3/01/2019   False   False
18  3/01/2019   True    True
19  3/01/2019   True    False
20  3/01/2019   True    False
21  3/01/2019   True    False
22  3/01/2019   False   False
23  3/01/2019   False   False
```

Comment: If one of the group do not have the True, idxmax will return the first False

Comment: You are right. I assumed there would be a true in each group. Like your answer, up-voted.

Comment: As YOBEN_S mentioned - works well but if there is a day with no TRUE (which in my case is the start of the data and very end), the first FALSE is TRUE.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC `duplicated`

```
s = (~df.duplicated())&df['True_False']
0     False
1     False
2      True
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10     True
11    False
12    False
13    False
14    False
15    False
16    False
17    False
18     True
19    False
20    False
21    False
22    False
23    False
dtype: bool

df['1stT'] = s
```

Comment: I can't get this working. **DF.insert(2, "True_False_2", (~DF.duplicated()) & DF['True_False'])**. The 2nd column is just a copy of the first.